# What's the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was going through the hooks documentation when I stumbled upon [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

Looking at their example…

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

…it seems like `useRef` can be replaced with `createRef`.

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputRef = createRef(); // what's the diff?
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputRef} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Why do I need a hook for refs? Why does `useRef` exist?

Answer (score 303, accepted):

The difference is that `createRef` will always create a new ref. In a class-based component, you would typically put the ref in an instance property during construction (e.g. `this.input = createRef()`). You don't have this option in a function component. `useRef` takes care of returning the same ref each time as on the initial rendering.

Here's an example app demonstrating the difference in the behavior of these two functions:

```
import React, { useRef, createRef, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const [renderIndex, setRenderIndex] = useState(1);
  const refFromUseRef = useRef();
  const refFromCreateRef = createRef();
  if (!refFromUseRef.current) {
    refFromUseRef.current = renderIndex;
  }
  if (!refFromCreateRef.current) {
    refFromCreateRef.current = renderIndex;
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      Current render index: {renderIndex}
      <br />
      First render index remembered within refFromUseRef.current:
      {refFromUseRef.current}
      <br />
      First render index unsuccessfully remembered within
      refFromCreateRef.current:
      {refFromCreateRef.current}
      <br />
      <button onClick={() => setRenderIndex(prev => prev + 1)}>
        Cause re-render
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit 1rvwnj71x3]

Comment: d= (^-^ ) good point that `ref` is not limited, and can even hold a simple number; But why is `.current` required (unlike `useState` hook)? **Found the reason:** just to make `.current` passable by reference, like a real class's field, without strange setter. (LOL, I wonder how far slower functional vs real class is nowadays.)

Answer (score 112):

### tldr

A `ref` is a plain JS object `{ current: <some value> }`.

`React.createRef()` is a factory returning a ref `{ current: null }` - [no magic involved](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabd/packages/react/src/ReactCreateRef.js#L12).

`useRef(initValue)` also returns a ref `{ current: initValue }` akin to `React.createRef()`. **Besides**, it [memoizes](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/6faf6f5/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactFiberHooks.js#L907-L920) this ref to be persistent across multiple renders in a *function component*.

It is sufficient to use `React.createRef` in class components, as the ref object is [assigned to an instance variable](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#creating-refs), hence accessible throughout the component and its lifecyle:

```
this.myRef = React.createRef(); // stores ref in "mutable" this context (class)
```

`useRef(null)` basically [**is equivalent to**](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1099842565631819776) `useState(React.createRef())[0]` <sup>**1**</sup>.

---

### <sup>1</sup> Replace `useRef` with `useState` + `createRef`

Following [tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1099842565631819776) has been enlightening for me:

> `useRef()` is basically `useState({current: initialValue })[0]`.

With insights from the `tldr` section, we now can further conclude:

> `useRef(null)` is basically `useState(React.createRef())[0]`.

Above code "abuses" `useState` to persist the returned ref from `React.createRef()`. `[0]` just selects the value part of `useState` - `[1]` would be the setter.

`useState` causes a re-render in contrast to `useRef`. More formally, React compares the old and new object reference for `useState`, when a new value is set via its setter method. If we *mutate* the state of `useState` directly (opposed to setter invocation), its behavior more or less becomes *equivalent* to `useRef`, as no re-render is triggered anymore:

```
// Example of mutating object contained in useState directly
const [ref] = useState({ current: null })
ref.current = 42; // doesn't cause re-render
```

<sub>Note: Don't do this! Use the optimized `useRef` API instead of reinventing the wheel. Above is for illustration purposes.</sub>

Comment: "useRef(null) is basically useState(React.createRef())[0]"  ... More like `useRef(null) is basically useState(() => React.createRef())[0]`, no? Otherwise `React.createRef()` would run every render.

Comment: The [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) is mainly for performance reasons (argument in non-function form would be disregarded in subsequent re-renders). As the example is used for illustration purposes and hypothetical, I guess it's easier to understand without function form. Good hint though.

Answer (score 71):

`createRef` always returns a new ref, which you'd generally store as a field on a class component's instance. `useRef` returns *the same ref* upon every render of a functional component's instance. This is what allows the state of the ref to persist between renders, despite you not explictly storing it anywhere.

In your second example, the ref would be re-created upon every render.

Comment: There's a comment here by one of the React devs explaining that this is how it works: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/a2pt15/when_would_you_use_reactcreateref_vs_reactuseref/eb17vz5/ I'd be interested to know what you think is incorrect about this answer.

Comment: I saw that link before I tried answering this question, where does it state this fact in the link you have shared? I couldn't find it? :)

Comment: The link I shared shows a simplified implementation of `useRef`, posted by one of the React developers. It is not the same as simply calling `createRef`, as `createRef` isn't a hook and doesn't persist any state between calls. Ryan Cogswell's answer also has a good example of the differences.

Comment: My understanding from that context only inferred that useRef is a custom hook that uses createRef inside. Thank you for sharing the knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Just to highlight a purpose:

`createRef` is as simple as `return {current: null}`. It's a way to handle `ref=` prop in most modern way and that's it(while string-based is toooo way magic and callback-based looks too verboose).

`useRef` keeps some data before renders and changing it does not cause re-render(as `useState` does). They are rarely related. Everything you expect for class-based component go to instance fields(`this.* =`) looks like candidate to be implemented with `useRef` in functional components.

Say `useCallback` works as bounded class methods(`this.handleClick = .....bind(this)`) and may be re-implemented(but we should not re-invent the wheel for sure) with `useRef`.

Another examples are DOM refs, timeout/interval IDs, any 3rd party libraries' identifiers or references.

PS I believe React team better chose different naming for `useRef` to avoid confusion with `createRef`. Maybe `useAndKeep` or even `usePermanent`.

Answer (score 1):

A ref is a plain JS object { current:  }.

```
React.useRef(initValue) return a ref { current: initValue }
    it is remember ref value across multiple render of function component.
It is advise to use in Function component
    
React.createRef(initValue) also return a ref  { current: initValue }
    it is not remember ref value across multiple render of function components. It is advise to use in class based component
```

Answer (score 0):

useRef and forwardRef are two different things in React with different use cases.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Focus input</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

And on the other hand:

```
import React, { forwardRef } from 'react';

const CustomInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <input type="text" ref={ref} />
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = React.createRef();

  const handleClick = () => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <CustomInput ref={inputRef} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Focus
   </div>
)
```