# How to use Refs in Function based Component

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-ref

Normally we can use `createRef()` in react class based component by writing `this.myRef = React.createRef();` insidide the constructor.

**My question is:**

Is there any way to use `ref` in function based component ?

**Here is the conventional way to use refs in class based component:**

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620698/whats-the-difference-between-useref-and-createref

Comment: React has [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook for that