# Migrate a React class component to a Function component (React-google-maps)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the `react-google-maps` library for a project and i found a perfect example for what i need. It is the code below and as you can see it is a class component.

```
class Map extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.map = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    const MyGoogleMap = withScriptjs(
      withGoogleMap(props => (
        <GoogleMap
          ref={map => {
            this.map = map;
          }}
        />
      ))
    );

    return(
      <MyGoogleMap />
    );
  }
}

export default Map
```

I want to migrate this class in a function component.

The lines i don't know how to implement to a function components is

`this.map = React.createRef();`

and

`ref={map => { this.map = map }}`

Comment: This might help https://janosh.io/blog/google-maps+react-hooks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [Function Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components), you use a [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook.

There is a subtle difference between `useRef` & `createRef`: refer to this post.
[What's the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620698/whats-the-difference-between-useref-and-createref)

Make sure to rid of `this.` in a function component.

```
function Map() {
  const mapRef = useRef();

  const MyGoogleMap = withScriptjs(
    withGoogleMap(props => <GoogleMap ref={mapRef} />)
  );

  return <MyGoogleMap />;
}
```