# Tabulator in React - TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabulator

I am getting this error...

```
  5440 | this.bindModules();
  5441 | 
> 5442 | if (this.element.tagName === "TABLE") {
       | ^  5443 |   if (this.modExists("htmlTableImport", true)) {
  5444 |     this.modules.htmlTableImport.parseTable();
  5445 |   }
```

When I attempt to use the [Tabulator library in a React component](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/frameworks#react).

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";
import "tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css";

function Journal(props) {

    let refTable = React.createRef();

    const [journalItems, setJournalItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        new Tabulator(refTable, {
            data: journalItems,
            reactiveData: true,
            columns: ["a", "b", "c"],
        });
    }, []); 

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="foo" ref={refTable}></div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Journal;
```

The [library example](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.5/frameworks#react) uses the class component approach, whereas I want to use the functional one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(this);` Is probably a good first step. Could be a simple case of `this` not meaning what you think `this` should be. Secondly, (if the `this` case checks out) is to see what `this.element` is. Is that `undefined`? I bet it is...

Comment: Isn't `this` not used in functional components?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue here - https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-wright-365ur .

createRef is not supposed to be used in functional components. Reference - [What's the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620698/whats-the-difference-between-useref-and-createref)

Only change needed is -

```
<div className="foo" ref={el => (refTable = el)} />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this like so...

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";
import "tabulator-tables/dist/css/tabulator.min.css";

function Journal(props) {

    let refTable = useRef(null);
    let table = useRef(null);

    const [journalItems, setJournalItems] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        table.current = new Tabulator(refTable.current, {
            data: journalItems,
            reactiveData: true,
            columns: ["a", "b", "c"],
        });
    }, []); 

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="foo" ref={refTable}></div>
        </div >
    )
}

export default Journal;
```

This was the problem.

*Assignments to the 'table' variable from inside React Hook useEffect will be lost after each render. 
To preserve the value over time, store it in a useRef Hook and keep the mutable value in the '.current' property. 
Otherwise, you can move this variable directly inside useEffect. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)*