# using useRef or createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, virtual-dom

I want to set the `const [solution, setSolution] = useState(0);`  with the value of a input element by pressing a button

I get the same result using `createRef` or using the `useRef` hook

reading [What's the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620836/14809198)

gives quit different answers what exactly thees to do, is there a clear inside about thees to methods ?

```
function Interface() {

    const [solution, setSolution] = useState(0);
  
    const solutionInp = useRef();
    //                --createRef();
    
    const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    setSolution( solutionInp.current.value)
      };


return (
 
<input
 type="text"
 // value={solution}
 
 ref={solutionInp}
 // onInput={(e) => setSolution(e.target.value)}
 />
 </section>
<button type="button" onClick={onButtonClick}>do</button>
)}
```

Comment: The link you provided gives all the answers. Use useRef in functional components, so it isnt recreated on rerender. In a class component use createState in the constructor  as that is only used once.

Comment: Have you check the docs? createRef is a part of Class component API and clearly you see `useRef` as part of hooks (function components) API.

Answer (score 3):

`createRef` is for **class components**, calling it in a context of function component **will be treated as a normal function**, hence will **RE-INITIAL** your reference on every render.

`useRef` is for **function components**, you lose your ref on unmount lifecycle.