# Should I use useRef over createRef with forwardRef?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Following up to [What's the difference between `useRef` and `createRef`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620698/whats-the-difference-between-useref-and-createref).  I have a functional component that uses `React.forwardRef`.

My question is specifically because of TypeScript failing.

Using

```
const textRef = createRef<typeof RNText>()
...
<HocText ref={textRef}>HocTextOne</HocText>
```

works correctly but

```
const textRef = useRef<typeof RNText>()
...
<HocText ref={textRef}>HocTextOne</HocText>
```

yields

> Type 'MutableRefObject<typeof Text | undefined>' is not assignable to type 'Ref | undefined'

Some articles show that we should be using `useRef` for functional components, but TypeScript is generating an error.

Forcing a cast like

```
const textRef = useRef<typeof RNText>() as RefObject<typeof RNText>
```

makes it compile but I am not sure if it is the right thing to do.

Comment: It's a side effect of how the type for useRef is defined, you can use `const textRef = useRef< typeof RNText >(null)` to fix this. This will change the type of the ref to RefObject

Comment: Your user name is pretty ironic considering the solution.  You can post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a side effect of how the type for `useRef` is defined, you can use `const textRef = useRef<typeof RNText>(null)` to fix this. This will change the type of the ref to `RefObject`