# Using createRef inside useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm using `createRef` inside `useRef`. Do you think this is redundant? Should I have an `audios` array and a separate `audioRefs` array, especially since `createRef` is probably doing nothing because it only works in class components?

```
import { useRef, createRef, forwardRef, MutableRefObject } from 'react';
import Slider from 'rc-slider';
import 'rc-slider/assets/index.css';

const audios = [
  {
    src: 'https://onlinetestcase.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/100-KB-MP3.mp3',
  },
];

interface Props {
  src: string;
}

const Audio = forwardRef<HTMLAudioElement, Props>(
  (props: Props, ref: MutableRefObject<HTMLAudioElement>) => {
    const { src } = props;

    function handleVolumeChange(value) {
      ref.current.volume = value / 100;
    }

    return (
      <>
        <audio ref={ref} loop>
          <source src={src} type="audio/mpeg" /> Your browser does not support
          the audio element.
        </audio>
        <Slider
          min={0}
          max={100}
          step={1}
          value={ref.current?.volume}
          onChange={handleVolumeChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
);

export const App = ({ name }) => {
  const audioRefs = useRef(
    audios.map((audio) => ({
      ...audio,
      ref: createRef<HTMLAudioElement>(),
    }))
  );

  function playAudio() {
    audioRefs.current?.forEach((audioRef) => audioRef.ref.current.play());
  }

  return (
    <>
      {audioRefs.current?.map((audioRef, index) => (
        <>
          <Audio key={audioRef.src} {...audioRef} />
          <button onClick={playAudio}>Play Audio</button>
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Live code at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-zask8v?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Really I'd recommend to just put the `<button>` inside the `<Audio>` component, makes everything simpler.

Comment: @Bergi The `playAudio` function plays all the audios. Not individual audios. I think I should have named it `playAudios`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for ref holding `current` is to have a consistent way to access the variable pointed to in the closure. So thinking about that holistically: yeah, I would say your feeling seems correct as you can simply map to one ref as you don't need all the nesting e.g.

```js
const audiosRef =  useRef(audios.map((audio) => ({
  ...audio,
  instance: null
});
```

And in your render you can use ref assignment in a method mapping through the audioRef:

```js
<audio ref={ r => audiosRef.current[index].instance = r }} />
```

Note that you may need to add a type e.g. `MutableRefObject<(Audio & { instance: HTMLAudio | null })[]>` or something along those lines to your ref if you go this route. If your intention was also definitively use `forwardRef`, you could pass an index to `Audio`.

Also: you may be repeatedly creating new refs as well in a functional component by going that route. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620836/1291659) for details.